# React, структура проекта, шрифты

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

я новичок в React и не понимаю куда складывать шрифты и как их подключать. У себя в проекте я использую модульную стилизацию. Они должны хранится в папке public или должны быть подключены в index.css? и где их лучше хранить

Comment: Вот здесь этот вопрос разбирался. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41676054/how-to-add-fonts-to-create-react-app-based-projects

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете создать папку fonts в директории src, и хранить шрифты локально (не рекомендую).
Вы так же можете подключить шрифты в глобальный CSS файл используя [@font-face](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face).
Хранение шрифтов в папке public не рекомендуется и применяется в качестве последнего средства.