# Подключение шрифтов в ReactJS

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, create-react-app

Подскажите, пожалуйста, куда лучше добавить шрифты: в src или public? Есть ли в этом какая-то разница? И как их подключить к проекту? Только начал изучение React, пытаюсь создать свое spa и не могу понять как правильно подключать шрифты. Буду благодарен за помощь)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Этот вопрос разбирался здесь:

- кратко ответ на русском
  [React, структура проекта, шрифты](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1328497/react-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%88%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%82%D1%8B)
- более подробно на английском
  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41676054/how-to-add-fonts-to-create-react-app-based-projects